# What is a dplyr equivalent for using which function?

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

I have a dataframe 1:

```
df1<- structure(list(`gaugelist[1:20, ]` = c(1094000L, 1094000L, 1094000L, 
1100600L, 1100600L, 1100600L, 1100600L, 1100600L, 1100600L, 1100600L, 
1100600L, 1100600L, 1100600L, 1100600L, 1096000L, 1100600L, 1100600L, 
1100600L, 1100600L, 1100600L)), .Names = "gaugelist[1:20, ]", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

And a second list:

```
df2 <- c("ts.01094000.crest.csv", "ts.01100600.crest.csv")
```

I want to make another column in df1 based on matching row values:

```
df1$test <- apply(df1, 1, function(x) df2[which(grepl(x,df2))])
```

1. What would be the dplyr way of making this work? I couldn't make rowwise work.
2. How can I make this work if df1 has large number of columns and I want to just one new column 'test' based on same rule.

Comment: Seems like there should be a smart way to vectorize what you're trying to do. Hmm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
df1 <- setNames(df1, "x") # rename column to `x` for brevity
df1 %>% rowwise() %>%
 mutate(test = df2[grep(x,df2)[1]])
# Source: local data frame [20 x 2]
# Groups: <by row>

# # A tibble: 20 × 2
#          x                  test
#      <int>                 <chr>
# 1  1094000 ts.01094000.crest.csv
# 2  1094000 ts.01094000.crest.csv
# 3  1094000 ts.01094000.crest.csv
```

---

*Explanation.* You did not explain why you "couldn't make rowwise work", but based on my own experience, you may have gotten this message

> Error: incompatible size (0), expecting 1 (the group size) or 1

if you use an expression like `df2[which(grepl(x,df2))]` in `mutate`, which occurs because one (or more) of the returned values has length 0 (i.e. no match was found in `df2`).  Using `mutate(test = df2[grep(x,df2)[1]])` addresses this problem.  In particular, note that `df2[grep(x,df2)[1]]` returns one and only one value.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Would this work if df1 has large number of columns and x refers to one of the columns instead of the only column?